# Alternating colours for first column

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am currently creating a table where I'd like the header row and the first column fixed. I'd like it so that the rows alternate colors (which I have achieved). However, when scrolling the table, the first column overlaps the body like this;

**First column overlapping body**

[image]

I can overcome the overlapping issue by giving this first column a background color but then I struggle to alternate the row colours. I have tried to use :nth-child (odd and even) but have had no luck and instead it colors the whole column. Does anyone know if it is even possible to achieve this?

I have a `codepen` with my progress so far found at;

https://codepen.io/fizaan-rasool/pen/xxbOrJo?editors=1100

```
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
            <th>head</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>head</th>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>head</th>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>head</th>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>head</th>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    div {
      min-width: 100%;
      overflow: scroll;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #3D3D3D;
      border-radius: 15px;
      color: white;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-weight: 100;
      height: 150px;
    }

    table {
      position: relative;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td, th {
      padding: 0.25em;
      min-width: 100px;
    }

    th:first-child {
      z-index: 100;
    /*   background: #3d3d3d; */
    }

    /* tbody th:nth-child(n+0){
      color: green;
    } */

    /* tbody tr th:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: green;
    } */

    thead th {
      position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      color: #76A8B0;
      background-color: #343434;
      font-weight: 100;
    }

    thead th:first-child {
      left: 0;
      z-index: 100;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #343434;
    }

    tbody th {
      position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
      height: 30px;
      z-index: 100;
    }

    tbody th:nth-child(odd) {
      font-weight: 100;
      z-index: 100;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even){
      background-color: #343434;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: red;
    }

    thead {
      text-align: left;
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th {
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: 100;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) th {
    background-color: #343434;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

this should fix it for you, i guess

Answer (score 0):

You are not far off. Here is a simple example

What you want is

`table > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}`

https://jsfiddle.net/omf6904v/

Comment: Apologies, this didn't resolve it for me. But thank you for the response